# Javascript: Make Rows Draggable Through Input Field Handles

Tags: javascript, text, input, draggable, drag

I have created a table with draggable rows.  Unfortunately, most of the rows are covered with a large textbox input element.  In order to drag the rows, you have to grab the row on the very edge just outside of the textbox.  Is there a way to allow the rows to be grabbed through the textboxes without destroying the textbox functionality? (i.e. relay the mouse drag event, but not the mouseclick event?)